# draw route on static image map iphone

Tags: iphone, dictionary, navigation

I'm developing a campus navigation app. 
I have an image which displays building on the campus.
I want draw a route from  the user location to destination building the use wants to go.
Wondering how to draw a route on static custom image.
Been searching on internet but cannot find any clue how to develop.
All documentation on internet are about drawing route on Google map.
any hint will be much much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I am having same kind of requirement in my application. How have you achieved this functionality finally?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to manually collect latitude and longitude information for each of your map image's four corners. You'll also have to manually specify, in terms of co-ordinates on the image, the position of every possible turning point in the building's corridors, stairs etc. Then you can get the device's current latitude and longitude (see the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)), translate it into a position on your image, and overlay a transparent view with a red line on it stopping at each of your manually collected waypoints. There remains the graph theory problem of finding the shortest route through the network of waypoints. I suggest [the A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a).